# sort list in list with comparator

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

i would like make a specific sort of my stream with comparator in Java 8.

I have 2 class like this:

```
public class A {
    private String mName;
    private List<B> mBObjects;

    public A(String name) {
        mBObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        mName = name;
    }

    public void addValue(B b) {
        mBObjects.add(b);
    }

    public List<B> getBObjects() {
        return mBObjects;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
}

public class B {
    private int mValue;

    public B(int value) {
        mValue = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }
}
```

I initialises theses list with this code:

```
List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<>();

//A 1
A a = new A("a1");
a.addValue(new B(20));
a.addValue(new B(12));
listOfA.add(a);

//A 2
a = new A("a2");
a.addValue(new B(3));
listOfA.add(a);


//A 3
a = new A("a1");
a.addValue(new B(2));
a.addValue(new B(26));
a.addValue(new B(6));
listOfA.add(a);
```

Now i print the lists with this code:

```
for(A a: listOfA) {
        System.out.print("A: "+a.getName());
        List<B> listOfB = a.getBObjects();
        for(B b:listOfB) {
            System.out.print(" ; notes: "+b.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

the result is:

```
A: a1 ; value: 20 ; value: 12 
A: a2 ; value: 3 
A: a1 ; value: 2 ; value: 26 ; value: 6
```

I add this code after:

```
listOfA = listOfA.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(A::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The new result of this lists is:

```
A: a1 ; value: 20 ; value: 12 
A: a1 ; value: 2 ; value: 26 ; value: 6 
A: a2 ; value: 3
```

For each A object, i would like sort the list mBObjects without make a foreach to obtain this result:

```
A: a1 ; value: 12 ; value: 20 
A: a1 ; value: 2 ; value: 6 ; value: 26 
A: a2 ; value: 3
```

Thank's !

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. Why do you want to avoid a for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a sort that mutates the original `List`, use [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) to avoid all the overhead of creating a new list. Afterwards, you can call `List#sort` on each of the `mBObjects`.

```
listOfA.sort(Comparator.comparing(A::getName));
listOfA.forEach(a -> a.getBObjects().sort(Comparator.comparingInt(B::getValue)));
```

Comment: I changed my answer to use `List#sort` instead of `Collections.sort` for brevity, but it will be the same.

Comment: You don’t need a `stream().forEach(…)` here. You can just call `forEach(…)` on the `List`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, I knew there was still something weird with that

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(B b:listOfB) {
     System.out.print(" ; notes: "+b.getValue());
 }
```

Could be changed into

```
listOfB.stream().sorted(Comperator.comparing(B::getValue)).foreach(note -> System.out.print(" ; notes: " + note.getValue());
```

I think this should fit your question.

Comment: Wait, I don't understand. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As you are just looking to sort the `B` objects in that `List<B> mBObjects`, it would be nice if you just make your `B` s *comparable* and add them to a `TreeSet` instead of an `ArrayList`.

```
mBObjects = new TreeSet<B>();

public class B implements Comparable<B>{
    private int mValue;

    //...
    public int compareTo(B b1){
       return this.mValue < b1.mValue? 1 : (this.mValue > b1.mValue? -1:0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `Integer.compare`. Also, a `TreeSet` wouldn't allow duplicates and won't be faster than sorting the list.